# LifetimeScope per module in AutoFac

Tags: c#, autofac

I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/858) but I should have ask here first so here is my problem:

**The Situation**

We have some common Interfaces in our Solution like `IWorker` and its implementation `Worker`.
This class need to be configured.

```
public class Worker : IWorker
{
   private string selectedTag;

   public string DoWork()
   {
       return this.selectedTag;
   }

   public void Configure(string tag)
   {
       this.selectedTag = tag;
   }
}
```

We are using a plugin like architecture with the help of AutoFacs Modules.
So it is comes from time to time that a module registers and configures a 'Worker':

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModel1>();
builder.RegisterType<Worker>()
            .OnActivating(x => x.Instance.Configure("Worker for ViewModel1"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

A similar code can be found in another module but with another configuration.

**The Problem**

The problem with this is pretty obvious. One registration of the module is overriding the other one and each time the container resolves an `IWorker` it uses only the last configuration.

**A Solution**

One solution I found in your docs is to use the Keyed function. With this I am able to key every worker with a specific tag. But my problem with this is that I have to use a `KeyFilterAttribute` in the retriving class, which is in my case not desired because we want to minimize the container dependency I only want Autofac specific in my module classes.

**A possible Solution?**

What I think is a better solution is something like module based lifetime scopes, so that I can configure the container to use a registration for each module.

```
    builder.RegisterType<Worker>()
               .OnActivating(x => x.Instance.Configure("Worker for ViewModel1"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and if I now register a module I want to tell the container it should create a new scope for this module like:

```
builder.RegisterModule<Module1>("NewLifetimeScope");
```

What do you think? Is this possible? Or is there another solution I have missed?

Note that in the end I am using Prism with autofac so I am not able to manually start new LifetimeScopes.
I attached a small [repo Solution](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/files/1115365/AutoFacScopePerLifetime.zip) with a unit test to see what I need.

**Updated Solution with Keys:**

I read the [link](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) from [Travis Illig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8116/travis-illig). In the documentation is another way you can use services registered with keys (not with `KeyFilterAttribute`).

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModel1>()
               .WithParameter(
                   new ResolvedParameter(
                       (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IWorker),
                       (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IWorker>("Worker1")));
builder.RegisterType<Worker>()
               .OnActivating(x => x.Instance.Configure("Worker for ViewModel1"))
               .Keyed<IWorker>("Worker1");
```

With this solution I can configure the dependencies just in my modules. I think I'm fine with it.

**Update**

To improve the readability of my modules I added a extension method `WithKeyedParameter` which encapsulates the registration.

```
 public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> WithKeyedParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type paramType, object key) where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
    {
        return registration.WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == paramType, (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed(key, paramType)));
    }
```

So that the registration looks like:

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModel1>().WithKeyedParameter(typeof(IWorker), "Worker1");
```

Comment: Have you read [this doc which covers very similar situations](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)? Tried metadata instead of keys? Used Lazy<T> to avoid active instantiation? (There's no such thing as module lifetime scope.)

Comment: If you do try those things, update your question with the results rather than answering in comments so others can see what you've tried all in one spot.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need *Module dependency* ? If you follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle your implementation should not depend on a specific implementation. What about relying on `IEnumerable<IWorker>`?

Comment: @TravisIllig thank you for the link. I think I can live with the Keyed registrations.

Comment: @CyrilDurand Thats the point my implementation does not depend on another implementation. But in the end I have to inject the correct configured worker to my ViewModel. It would work with any Worker but in the current use case from the ViewModel it needs the configured Worker.

Comment: Check also [this nice example of typed metadata](https://alexmg.com/selectively-resolving-services-at-runtime-with-autofac/).

Comment: @AntonKrouglov thank you for the link. But in my case there will be nearly no difference to the solution with keys, because I have no predefined amount of Worker. I have a not known count of modules which may all contain a worker which needs its own configuration. And a ViewModel only needs one specific configured worker. The other workers are useless for the ViewModel.